# how to check file extensions with an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check if an extension is part of an array:
So: if an extension is not part of a forbidden array; do something is allowed

```
 $ext = $path_info['extension'];

 $ForbiddenExts = array("php", "html", "htm");
 if( $ext != in_array($ForbiddenExts)){
 // do something allowed
```

Comment: `if(  ! in_array($ext, $ForbiddenExts)){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
$ext = $path_info['extension'];

$ForbiddenExts = array("php", "html", "htm");
if(!in_array($ext, $ForbiddenExts))
{
   // do something
}
```

Check [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Other than using

```
if( $ext != in_array($ForbiddenExts)){
```

You can use

```
if(!in_array($ext, $ForbiddenExts)){
 //your code
}
```

**You have to practice checking the mime type too. Otherwise it may cause errors.**

> for eg: if someone edit the extension of a ".txt" file to ".pdf"
>   (assuning pdf is allowed type). Then if you don't check mime type, the
>   code will accept the file as pdf

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
$fileName = 'banner.jpg';
$fileNameParts = explode('.', $fileName);
echo $ext = end($fileNameParts);

$allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");
if(in_array($ext, $allowed_extensions))
{
   echo 'Allowed Extension';
   // do something
}else{
   echo 'Not Allowed Extension';
   // do something
}
```

Check this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for more explanation.